# restoring grub mint 17

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2

I'm currently trying to get my Mint 17 partition booting again.

I tried to fix a booting problem with boot-repair and a live USB, but upon inputting the command

sudo chroot "/mnt/boot-sav/sda7" 
apt-get install -y --force-yes grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed linux-signed-generic"

I got the error

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-signed-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 3.13.0.54.61) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

I reinstalled grub with a different method after lots of struggle (since this just wiped grub off), but then could only boot to a grub command prompt. Tried boot-repair again, and am now once again booting to nothing.

My main problem right now is I don't know what I need to fix. I'm not sure if I can go anywhere after reaching the blank grub command prompt, but I don't know how else to fix grub. Is the blank grub simply a problem of then mounting the kernel, or should grub already recognize the kernel?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up following several guides to boot from rescue grub. I unfortunately overlooked one problem the whole time; my grub folder in /boot was actually named grub.bak.

I then followed these instructions to boot from rescue grub:

set prefix=(hdx,y)/boot/grub.bak (instead of set prefix=(hdx,y)/boot/grub)

set root=(hdx,y)

insmod normal

normal